Why is the array cut and handled in a very enigmatic way, when trying to apply the Fisher-Yates algorithm in React?
I want to shuffle an Array of data, I fetched using apollo/client, inside an App I am writing with React. The data is used for interaction with the API, but it's not needed for rendering.
I fetched the data and handed the array to a function. In this function I want the array to be shuffled using the Fisher-Yates algorithm. I attempted different ways of writing the function with and without destructuring the array. When I logged the process of calculation in the console, I found that the Array which should have been shuffled often got cutten dramatically. It had a length of 1 - 3 items, while the unshuffled one contained 13 elements. The cutting appeared after looping through the elements to swap them. This, obviously, let to other problems in my script.
It also seems that the cutting of an array occurs on other operations as well. But I don't understand when and why.
I googled around the problem and also asked ChatGPT, but after several hours, I am hoping maybe someone here can give me a hint where to look closer.
Here is the function using Array destructuring:
function getShuffledArray(unshuffledArray) {
  const array = [...unshuffledArray];
  let currentIndex = array.length - 1;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    if (currentIndex !== randomIndex) {
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex],
        array[currentIndex],
      ];
    }
    currentIndex -= 1;
  }
  return array;
}

Then I also tried it without destructuring:
function getShuffledArray(unshuffledArray) {
  const array = [...unshuffledArray];
  let currentIndex = array.length - 1;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    if (currentIndex !== randomIndex) {
      const tempValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = tempValue;
    }
    currentIndex -= 1;
  }
  return array;
}

And I also tried using a way with the reduce-function:
 const newArray = array.reduce((modifiedArray, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    const tempValue = modifiedArray[randomIndex];
    modifiedArray[randomIndex] = currentValue;
    modifiedArray[currentIndex] = tempValue;
    return modifiedArray;
  }, array);



I tried to use useState, so its clearer to distinguish between the changing data and the set data. But in this case the looping got limited by some React-mechanism at one point to prevent an infinite Loop.
I also tried to useRef, since it is used for something, which does not influence rendering (which is the case in this situation). But the array also turned out to be read-only.

At all I have the vague idea it is some problem with read-only arrays in React, but I don't understand the framework and JavaScript good enough to tackle the problem. I started coding with JavaScript just a few months ago.
Edit: I worked around the problem by shuffling an Array of Indices.
I had an Issue that the Array of Objects didn't behave properly. It was close to that one: Javascript Array of objects is returning a shorter length than it should. I think it was a problem in the Browserengine or on a totally different part of my code. Trying to reproduce it now, I find it working fine.

You're making this vastly more complicated than it should be.

If you have an implementation that shuffles in place (such as the one in the linked question), and you want to shuffle a copy instead, just create the copy before passing it into that function Eg: const newArray = [...oldArray]; shuffle(newArray)

Thanks. I know, I was overcomplicating. But I think I had another underlying error.
